# Getting string from Json

Tags: java, android, json, string

I am new in json.My question is very simple.I have some array in my json file and also a string type of data.

Now I want to get the single text, name: **anounce** in my java class from json file.
How can i get this string from json ?
or any other way to get this ?

**Json file**

```
[{
        "title": "KalerKantha | OfftechIT",
        "image": "",
        "link": "http://www.kalerkantho.com/"

    }, {
        "title": "Prothom Alo | OfftechIT",
        "image": "",
        "link": "http://www.prothom-alo.com/"
    },
    ... 
   {
        "anounce": "I need this this text"
    }

]
```

**Java Code**

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        hidePDialog();

        // Parsing json
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {

                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                movie.setLink(obj.getString("link").toString());
                // adding movie to movies array
                movieList.add(movie);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // notifying list adapter about data changes
        // so that it renders the Grid view with updated data
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
            hidePDialog();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " No Internet connection! \n Please check you connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }};
});
```

Comment: Is it always going to be in the last object of the array?

Comment: No,It's a single object.

Comment: check obj.has("anounce") then add other wise ignore you can do this for all object

Comment: Then post full json. From your json it looks like as the last element of the array.

Comment: You might be interested in [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), it is wonderful.

Comment: @AovinMahmud ...Check my below solution, it can be helpful for you

Comment: This is the Json file link - [Json link] (http://api.offtechitbd.com/json/newspaper.json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply make check the **announce** is present in the `JSON` or not

```
      for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {

            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

            if(obj.has("anounce"))
            {
             String anounce= obj.getString("anounce");

            }
            else
            {
             Movie movie = new Movie();
             movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
             movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
             movie.setLink(obj.getString("link").toString());
             // adding movie to movies array
             movieList.add(movie);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @AovinMahmud ..Are you getting any error or exception,please let me know

Comment: Getting no text :( The scrolling text view is black :(

Comment: `scrollingtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_annouc);
        scrollingtext.setText(anounce);
        scrollingtext.setSelected(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `optString` method. It would return the value if node exists and `String.empty` is node is not found.

[From Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString%28java.lang.String%29)

> public String optString (String name)
>
> *Returns the value mapped by name if it exists, coercing it if necessary, or the empty string if no such mapping exists.*

Do this

```
try {

    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

    String announce = obj.optString("anounce");

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setTitle(obj.optString("title"));
    movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.optString("image"));
    movie.setLink(obj.optString("link"));
    // adding movie to movies array
    movieList.add(movie);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update:** Using `optString` is much better, but if you don't want to use it then do this

```
try {

    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

    if(i == response.length() -1)
    {
        String announce = obj.getString("anounce");
    }
    else
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
        movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
        movie.setLink(obj.getString("link").toString());
        // adding movie to movies array
        movieList.add(movie);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Print the value of `announce` after for loop. Does it show anything. Why don't you use second method I have answered.

Comment: How can i set this in my scrolling text.Code bellow not working .`scrollingtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_annouc);
        scrollingtext.setText(anounce);
        scrollingtext.setSelected(true);`

Comment: Define `String announce` at class level and use this variable in try block. In which method you are trying to set the value?

Answer (score 1):

The Structure of your `JSON` is hard. But if you really want to get the string. Try this. Add this inside in for loop.

```
String data = (obj.getString("announce") != null) ? obj.getString("announce") : "";
                       // If you Movie has this annouce in your settler Getter if not try to add it.
Movie.setAnnounce(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code look like good but Are you add the request to queue
like:-

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
```

movieReq is `JsonArrayRequest`,
Please check it. and

```
               String manounce=obj.getString("anounce");
```